# IntelliJ conda integration

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pip, pycharm, conda

I have in myFile.py:

```
import pkg_resources
installed_packages = pkg_resources.working_set
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
                                  for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
import rospy
```

I do have ros package in `ros` env

```
(ros) $ pip list | grep rospy
rospy                         1.11.21   
rospy-message-converter       0.4.0
```

If I run this file from IDEA after setting up `ros` conda env

```
/home/username/anaconda3/envs/ros/bin/python /home/username/Projects/Python/myProject/myFile.py
['argparse==1.4.0', 'catkin-pkg==0.4.9', 'certifi==2018.10.15', 'docutils==0.14', 'numpy==1.15.4', 'pip==18.1', 'pyparsing==2.3.0', 'python-dateutil==2.7.5', 'python==2.7.15', 'pyyaml==3.13', 'rospkg==1.1.7', 'setuptools==40.6.2', 'six==1.11.0', 'wheel==0.32.3', 'wsgiref==0.1.2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Projects/Python/myProject/myFile.py", line 8, in <module>
    import rospy
ImportError: No module named rospy

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I used the following configuration:

[image]

However, if I run the same on terminal, it just works:

On terminal, even without `conda activate ros`:

```
$ /home/username/anaconda3/envs/ros/bin/python /home/username/Projects/Python/myProject/myFile.py
['actionlib==1.11.13', 'angles==1.9.11', 'argparse==1.4.0', 'base-local-planner==1.12.16', 'bondpy==1.7.20', 'camera-calibration-parsers==1.11.13', 'camera-calibration==1.12.23', 'camera-info-manager-py==0.2.3', 'capabilities==0.2.0', 'catkin-pkg==0.4.9', 'catkin==0.6.19', 'certifi==2018.10.15', 'controller-manager-msgs==0.9.7', 'controller-manager==0.9.7', 'create-dashboard==2.3.1', 'create-driver==2.3.0', 'create-node==2.3.0', 'cv-bridge==1.11.16', 'diagnostic-analysis==1.9.3', 'diagnostic-common-diagnostics==1.9.3', 'diagnostic-updater==1.9.3', 'docutils==0.14', 'dynamic-reconfigure==1.5.49', 'gazebo-plugins==2.4.16', 'gazebo-ros==2.4.16', 'gencpp==0.5.5', 'genlisp==0.4.15', 'genmsg==0.5.8', 'genpy==0.5.10', 'image-geometry==1.11.16', 'interactive-markers==1.11.3', 'kobuki-dashboard==0.4.2', 'laser-geometry==1.6.4', 'message-filters==1.11.21', 'numpy==1.15.4', 'openni2-launch==0.4.1', 'pip==18.1', 'pluginlib==1.10.7', 'pyparsing==2.3.0', 'python-dateutil==2.7.5', 'python-qt-binding==0.2.19', 'python==2.7.15', 'pyyaml==3.13', 'qt-dotgraph==0.2.33', 'qt-gui-cpp==0.2.33', 'qt-gui-py-common==0.2.33', 'qt-gui==0.2.33', 'resource-retriever==1.11.8', 'rocon-app-manager==0.7.13', 'rocon-app-utilities==0.7.13', 'rocon-apps==0.7.13', 'rocon-console==0.1.23', 'rocon-ebnf==0.1.23', 'rocon-gateway-utils==0.7.10', 'rocon-gateway==0.7.10', 'rocon-hub-client==0.7.10', 'rocon-hub==0.7.10', 'rocon-interactions==0.1.23', 'rocon-launch==0.1.23', 'rocon-master-info==0.1.23', 'rocon-python-comms==0.1.23', 'rocon-python-redis==0.1.23', 'rocon-python-utils==0.1.23', 'rocon-python-wifi==0.1.23', 'rocon-qt-library==0.7.12', 'rocon-remocon==0.7.12', 'rocon-semantic-version==0.1.23', 'rocon-uri==0.1.23', 'rosbag==1.11.21', 'rosboost-cfg==1.11.14', 'rosclean==1.11.14', 'roscreate==1.11.14', 'rosgraph==1.11.21', 'roslaunch==1.11.21', 'roslib==1.11.14', 'roslint==0.10.0', 'roslz4==1.11.21', 'rosmake==1.11.14', 'rosmaster==1.11.21', 'rosmsg==1.11.21', 'rosnode==1.11.21', 'rosparam==1.11.21', 'rospkg==1.1.7', 'rospy-message-converter==0.4.0', 'rospy==1.11.21', 'rosservice==1.11.21', 'rostest==1.11.21', 'rostopic==1.11.21', 'rosunit==1.11.14', 'roswtf==1.11.21', 'rqt-action==0.4.9', 'rqt-bag-plugins==0.4.8', 'rqt-bag==0.4.8', 'rqt-console==0.4.8', 'rqt-dep==0.4.9', 'rqt-graph==0.4.8', 'rqt-gui-py==0.4.8', 'rqt-gui==0.4.8', 'rqt-image-view==0.4.9', 'rqt-launch==0.4.8', 'rqt-logger-level==0.4.8', 'rqt-moveit==0.5.7', 'rqt-msg==0.4.8', 'rqt-nav-view==0.5.7', 'rqt-plot==0.4.8', 'rqt-pose-view==0.5.8', 'rqt-publisher==0.4.8', 'rqt-py-common==0.4.8', 'rqt-py-console==0.4.8', 'rqt-reconfigure==0.4.10', 'rqt-robot-dashboard==0.5.7', 'rqt-robot-monitor==0.5.7', 'rqt-robot-steering==0.5.9', 'rqt-runtime-monitor==0.5.7', 'rqt-rviz==0.5.7', 'rqt-service-caller==0.4.8', 'rqt-shell==0.4.9', 'rqt-srv==0.4.8', 'rqt-tf-tree==0.5.8', 'rqt-top==0.4.8', 'rqt-topic==0.4.10', 'rqt-web==0.4.8', 'rviz==1.11.19', 'sensor-msgs==1.11.10', 'setuptools==40.6.2', 'six==1.11.0', 'smach-ros==2.0.1', 'smach==2.0.1', 'smclib==1.7.20', 'tf-conversions==1.11.9', 'tf2-geometry-msgs==0.5.17', 'tf2-kdl==0.5.17', 'tf2-py==0.5.17', 'tf2-ros==0.5.17', 'tf2-sensor-msgs==0.5.17', 'tf==1.11.9', 'unique-id==1.0.5', 'warehouse-ros==0.8.8', 'wheel==0.32.3', 'world-canvas-client-py==0.1.0', 'world-canvas-server==0.1.0', 'world-canvas-utils==0.1.0', 'wsgiref==0.1.2', 'xacro==1.9.5']
```

So IDEA is not executing the printed command? Is it running something else? Why do I see way less installed packages for the conda env `ros` running from inside IDEA and how do I resolve this issue?

I'm on

- IDEA 2018.3
- Ubuntu 14.04

Update:

I have configured the conda env and I verified it like this:

On terminal:

```
$ conda activate ros
(ros) $ python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 13 2018, 23:04:45) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/home/username/anaconda3/envs/ros/bin/python
```

On Python Console from IDEA > Tools > Python Console

```
PyDev console: starting.
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 13 2018, 23:04:45) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
import sys
print(sys.executable)
/home/username/anaconda3/envs/ros/bin/python
```

Comment: Did you configure the project interpreter to be the `ros` env? run `print(sys.executable)` from both your working setup and in pycharm, and see if they vary.

Comment: yep, updated the question.

Comment: `rospy` appears on your `conda list` as well, when on the `ros` env?

Comment: nope, rospy is not a conda package

Answer (score 0):

When you tried to run this script in the system terminal (outside of IDEA), were you using **the same interpreter**? If not, please try again but use the same interpreter you use in IDEA. Do you have the same error?

If not, try the following:

- run `import os` in the system terminal using **the same interpreter**
- run `print(os.environ['PATH'])`
- copy the result and add as `PATH` environment variable to your Run/Debug Configuration